# Disable auto closing for HTML comments in VS Code

Tags: html, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, comments

I have

```
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false
```

in my settings and it works fine for all tags except for HTML comments. When I type `<!--` it autocompletes with `-->`. I went through other options in editor and HTML and can't find how to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Change the second setting you have to this:

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never"
```

That should fix it.